# nginx rewrite: rewrite and pass original URI arguments along

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I simply want to rewrite:

`https://example.com/id/123?a=1&b=2` *(and maybe more variables, or maybe none)*

to

`https://example.com/load.php?id=123&a=1&b=2` *(...and whatever others, or maybe none after `id`)*

That's it. So simple, right?

Yet I think there is a secret unwritten rule that says docs for nginx URL rewriting must be dense, unclear, and devoid of any useful examples. ;-) I have googled and experimented for a while now. Can't get it to fly.

I tried this, and several variations of it, with no luck:
`rewrite ^/id/(.*)$ /load.php?id=$1&$args last;`

I think I'm close. Can you help?

Comment: The remaining arguments are appended automatically. Try: `rewrite ^/id/(.*)$ /load.php?id=$1 last;`

Comment: It wasn't working and now it is--- crazy. Thank you. If you want to add this comment as an answer I'm happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rewrite` directive automatically appends the original arguments (adding a `?` or `&` separator as required) unless the replacement string ends with a `?`.

For example:

```
rewrite ^/id/(.*)$ /load.php?id=$1 last;
```

The above will internally redirect `/id/123?x=abc` to `/load.php?id=123&x=abc`.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.